Failing to upgrade Oracle Linux 7.9 to 8.10 via leapp
Leapp upgrade of Oracle Linux 7.9 to 8.10 fails and drops in emergency mode. This happens when I select EL8 kernel in grub menu. System seems to be working normally with EL7 kernel. Systems are virtualized in VMWare.
While entering into emergency mode, this message appears:
Warning: /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX does not exist 

I tried to use /dev/sda3 instead, but it fails with same message, only it complains about /dev/sda3 missing.
leapp preupgrade generated report has no inhibitors, but what puzzles me are these two high factor messages:
Risk Factor: high Title: Leapp detected loaded kernel drivers which are no longer maintained in OL 8. Summary: The following OL 7 device drivers are no longer maintained OL 8:
         - mptbase
         - mptscsih
         - mptspi
    
Key: d3dc36baebfba8ca1c73bbc031f4c8fa07bcfd6f
---------------------------------------- 
Risk Factor: high Title: GRUB core will be updated during upgrade Summary: On legacy (BIOS) systems, GRUB core (located in the gap between the MBR and the first partition) does not get automatically updated when GRUB is upgraded. Key: baa75fad370c42fd037481909201cde9495dacf4
----------------------------------------

I somehow suspect the three modules to be the problem.
On the other hand, when I run clean OL8 instance, install the kernel-modules package and load the modules, it works. Even when I add them into /etc/modules-load.d/ so they are loaded at boot.
Do you have any ideas how to fix this?
Tried to unload the modules and regenerate initramfs, still fails.

Turned out it was due to VMWare guest running an LSI storage controller, which is no longer supported by the RHCK on OL8. Options were either to switch controller to VMWare Paravirtual on Hypervisor side, or upgrade OL7 to latest UEK, install kerne-transition, erase old kernel (yum erase kernel) and start the leapp from scratch.
